# Алгоритм распределения конфет между детьми)

Tags: алгоритм, математика, комбинаторика

Есть рандомное количество конфет. Нужно вывести все возможные варианты распределения этих конфет между 3мя детьми.
Натолкните, пожалуйста, на мысль.

```
static void Main() 
  {
      Random rnd = new Random();
      int prize = rnd.Next(0, 100); // конфеты
      int[] arr = new int[3] {0, 0, 0}; // дети
      
     .... 
      
    foreach (int q in arr) Console.Write((int)q + " ");
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
```

Если, например, конфеты - 4, то в итоге должно получиться что-то вроде:

- 4 0 0
- 3 1 0
- 3 0 1
- 2 2 0
- ...
- 0 0 4

Comment: Вы хотите выписать все разложения целого неотрицательного числа в виде суммы фиксированного количества целых неотрицательных слагаемых?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как C# я не знаю, считайте, что это псевдокод :) — вывод допишите сами.

```
for(int i1 = 0; i1 <= N; ++i1)
    for(int i2 = 0; i2 <= N - i1; ++i2)
        // Вывести i1, i2, N - i1 - i2
```

Вот на С++: https://ideone.com/YI5ncr

Если не ошибся, то общее число способов разделить `x` конфет между `n` детей -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. для трех детей `x` конфет — `(x+2)*(x+1)/2`.

Comment: хах, по 2 итерации у меня и у вас и мы пришли к идентичному коду =)

Comment: @tym32167 Ну дык, задача-то одна :)

Answer (score 1):

решите вложенную задачу (через рекурсию)

есть `N` детей и `X` конфет

1. первый ребенок получает `y=1..X-N+1` конфет
2. для каждого случая вызываем тот же алгоритм, но уже для `N - 1` детей и `X - y` конфет
3. подсчет всех случаев считаем по последнему ребенку

Кстати отсюда можно вывести и общую формулу ;-)

1 ребенок получает `X - N + 1` вариантов конфет

2 ребенок получает `(X - N + 1) - 1` вариантов конфет (детей стало на 1 меньше

и т.д.

и получится простая формула в которой будет присутствовать вот такой символ `!`

Answer (score 0):

Простой цикл, распределит конфеты и возможные остатки выкинет

```
var rand = new Random();
var n = rand.Next(1, 10);

Console.WriteLine($"всего конфет {n}");

for(int i=0; i<=n; i++) 
    for(int j=0; j<=(n-i); j++)     
        for(int k=0; k<=(n-i-j); k++)           
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} {j} {k}");
```

Вывод

```
всего конфет 1
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 0
```

Если нужно, чтобы сумма кофет у детей была всегда равна N

```
var rand = new Random();
var n = rand.Next(1, 10);

Console.WriteLine($"всего конфет {n}");

for(int i=0; i<=n; i++) 
    for(int j=0; j<=(n-i); j++)                 
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} {j} {n-i-j}");
```

Вывод

```
всего конфет 3
0 0 3
0 1 2
0 2 1
0 3 0
1 0 2
1 1 1
1 2 0
2 0 1
2 1 0
3 0 0
```